# Node.js Sequalize using create function in a loop on multiple models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

this is driving me nuts, I've spent hours pulling my hair out - classic. I am receiving data from an API endpoint. I'm looping through the data and needing to create multiple records in multiple tables, and need to use the last inserted id of the first created record. But I'm not getting the correct results:

Code of the request:

```
request(options, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }

  for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {

    var contact = {
      name: body[i].person.first_name + " " + body[i].person.last_name
    };
    var article = {
      name: body[i].article.name,
      author: null // want this to be last inserted id of contact, after it's saved.
    };

    var note = {
      text: body[i].person.first_name+" wrote an article.",
      contactId: null // want this to be last inserted id of contact, after it's saved.
    };

    Contact.create(contact).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result.id);
      note.contactId = result.id;
      article.author = result.id;
      Article.create(article).then();
      Note.create(note.then();

    });
  }
}
```

The result is that the Contact gets saved but not the rest. My JS chops are not great, so I think I'm hitting async issues or maybe lack of skill, but I've search around and not finding examples of looping model creating.

Please can you help me get back on the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use bluebird and chain then promises.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    return Promise.each(body, (item) =>  {
        const contact = {
            name: `${item.person.first_name} ${item.person.last_name}`,
        };
        const article = {
            name: item.article.name,
            author: null,
        };
        const note = {
            text: `${item.person.first_name} wrote an article.`,
            contactId: null,
        };

        return Contact.create(contact)
            .then( (result) => {
                console.log(result.id);
                note.contactId = result.id;
                article.author = result.id;
            })
            .then(() => Article.create(article))
            .then(() => Note.create(note));
    })
};
```

or async/await

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    return Promise.each(body, async (item) => {
        const result = await Contact.create(contact = {
            name: `${item.person.first_name} ${item.person.last_name}`,
        });

        await Article.create({
            name: item.article.name,
            author: result.id,
        });

        await Note.create({
            text: `${item.person.first_name} wrote an article.`,
            contactId: result.id,
        });
    })
};
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Uladzislau ! Bluebird is really nice. Any reason to prefer async/await over using .then()? Is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Yes, I suggest using async/await